# Android Studio NavigationView can not create listview

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

Help me! NavigationView can not create listview. I want create list menu in NavigationView slide right.

Code no error It can not be run error

> : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{jp.vertice.myapplication/jp.vertice.myapplication.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        String[] values = new String[] { "List 1",
                "List 2",
                "List 3",
                "List 4",
                "List 5"
        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                int itemPosition     = position;

                String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : " + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_menu_right" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_menu_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code, please replace with your code. The reason for NullPointerException was you are trying to find the listView directly but the listView is the Header of NavigationView, so first you need to find the view for NavigationView then get the header from NavigationView and using that header you can find the listView you wanted.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { 
        ListView listView;
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        NavigationView navigationViewRight = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view_right);
        View header = navigationViewRight.getHeaderView(0);
        listView = (ListView) header.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        String[] values = new String[] { "List 1",
                "List 2", 
                "List 3", 
                "List 4", 
                "List 5" 
        }; 

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override 
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                int itemPosition     = position;

                String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : " + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show(); 
            } 
        }); 
    }
```